# Google Apps Script Upload Large Files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to set up an upload form to upload large video files but the Google Apps Script has a 6 minute execution limit. Is there any way other I could upload those files directly to a folder on my Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Apps Script to upload large files as there's not just an execution limit of 6 minutes but also a daily bandwidth limit on URLFetch service. You are likely to exhaust the quota if you try uploading a file that is few 100s of MB.